# How to change the weight of ticks and label of colorbar in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I wrote a plot function like this:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plotPot(func, title):

    plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(2, 1.8), dpi=800, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    font = {'family': 'DejaVu Sans', 'size': 8}
    mpl.rc('font', **font)
    mpl.rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 12

    xi = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
    yi = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

    Z = func(X, Y)

    plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='RdGy')


    plt.xlabel("x / kpc")
    plt.xticks(fontsize=5)

    plt.ylabel("y / kpc")
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-10, 15, step=5))
    plt.yticks(fontsize=5)

    tick_locator = mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(extend='neither', spacing='proportional',
                        orientation='vertical', shrink=1)
    cbar.locator = tick_locator
    cbar.update_ticks()
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=5, grid_alpha=0.5, direction='in')
    cbar.set_label(label=r'$g^{2}/cm^{2}$', size='small', weight='light')

    return cbar
```

and the given plot is:
[image]

as you can see, the ticks and label of the plot are all bold. How can I change them all in a lighter form?

Comment: Your code produces [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IZAn.png) (when defining all undefined variables) for me. For some reason your figure seems much too small; can you confirm that this is really the code that produces the image?

Comment: You can pass the `fontweight` to the ticks: `plt.yticks(fontsize=5, fontweight='normal')`. In the dictonaries at the top of [this file](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/font_manager.html) you can see all the options

Comment: yes, I am sure this is the code produces the image. Even I changed the figure size, those fonts are still bold in colorbar.

Comment: fontweight only changes the x-y ticks, but could you explain how to change that of ticks of colorbar?

Comment: In my experience, defining figure size does not always work as expected and it is not the same for every output. Try defining the figure.figsize through plt.rcParams instead and save your figure to a png file. That should give you something more similar to what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest sees.

Comment: `plt.setp(cbar.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels(), weight='normal', fontsize=5)` should work, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35728847/7570817)

Comment: @JanVorac Figure size needs to be consistent. If it isn't, that would be a bug and would need to be reported (but honestly, I doubt that's the case). As a consequence I can tell for sure that the code shown cannot produce the figure shown in the question, because that figure is not 4 by 3.3 inches.